# Custom control for searchnig using leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I need to move functionality for search something on map from normal page to leaflet controls on map. I'm searching for plugin to start with. Is it good idea to use a normal search plugin or it will be difficult to make it look like on the image? Does exist something like the base plugin to make custom controls?

[Visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTzH6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Leaflet.Control.Search](https://leaflet-search.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/simple.html), here's an [example](https://leaflet-search.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/simple.html)

If you want to go outside the map, [`here's another example`](http://jsfiddle.net/ralu_bur/synjrLze/4/)